# Spring batch how to skip entire file on condition

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have Spring batch job that reads some files and persists it to DB. If I need to be able to code some custom condition and skip file processing if it does not meet the condition. I've tried to extend ItemReader and throw exception but it caused whole job to fail while I need job to continue to iterate over files.

Thanks

Comment: Some of your code would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up with extending MultiResourceItemReader and overriding read() method. Before delegate file to actual ItemReader, it validates the condition and pass file to reader only in case condition passed, otherwise processing to next file

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipPolicy interface. I give you an example extracted from [Pro Spring Batch written by T. Minella](http://www.apress.com/9781430234524)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipLimitExceededException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipPolicy;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;

public class FileVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {

public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {

if(exception instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
       return false;
} else if(exception instanceof ParseException && skipCount <= 10) {
       return true;
} else {
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Inside your xml file :

```
<step id="copyFileStep">
  <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="customerItemReader" writer="outputWriter"
commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
      <skippable-exception-classes>
        <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
        <exclude class="org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException"/>
      </skippable-exception-classes>
    </chunk>
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

Or maybe another way could be to add at the beginning of your job a step wich sort your input files into two separate folder. Inside one folder you will have all your wrong files and inside the other folder only good ones remain.

Comment: SkipPolicy operates on chunk level while I need to operate on file level so I guess this is not the way

Comment: Maybe another way could be to add at the beginning of your job a step wich sort your input files into two separate folder. Inside one folder you will have all your wrong files and inside the other folder only good ones remain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added the answer with solution I've managed to get.

Comment: @Evgeny Makarov I have edited my post to add my comment inside for more visibility. If you consider it as a possible answer could you accept it if of course you can't accept your own answer ?

Comment: as I already said, this will work on chunk level and this is not solution for me. Moreover sort files is possible however this will affect job performance as I have to process hundred of gigabytes of files so I prefer to filter "bad" files on the fly

Answer (score 1):

override the doRead() method of your reader and throw your app specific exception.
E.g :

```
*CustomFlatFileItemReader
    @Override
    protected T doRead() throws Exception {
        T itemRead=null;
        try {
            itemRead=   super.doRead();
        } catch (FlatFileParseException e) {
            throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    return itemRead;
}*
```

2. Set the skipPolicy of the job to skip MyException.

```
*.skipPolicy((Throwable T, int skipCount) -> {
                    if (T instanceof MyException)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }*
```

Comment: But in my case, I will know that I need to skip the file only in processor post reading the file. My job looks like below

`  @Bean
  @Qualifier(PAYMOD_REFUND_ECHO_FILE_JOB)
  public Job payModRefundInEchoBatchJob() {
   return jobBuilderFactory.get("paymodrefundinechofile")
     .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
     .start(prepareRefundEchoFlatFile())
     .next(SendRefundEchoFileViaSFTP())
     .listener(getRefundEchoFileListner())
     .build();
  }